Add Run Button to the line in RStudio
In a tutorial video on youtube I've seen that is possible to add a Run button on the right side of each line where the cursor is placed.
It's very interesting, but unfortunately I can't recall the name of the channel or the vid. I've seen it last year during a project. (for those willing to try a spin looking for it, I guess the topic was PCA, and I recall for sure the teacher was a woman)
Any idea on how to do it?
I've tried searching for a suitable way, but 99% of explanations concern normal shortcuts
Thanks to anyone who will help

You may be thinking of RMarkdown. In RStudio, create new file and select R Markdown. Then, go into the "Visual" editor. Code blocks will have a "Run" button next to them.
Also, in a normal R script you can run a single line by pressing Ctrl + Enter.

Yes and no. Yes, the kind of button is precisely that. No, I tried following your instructions, but  both in Source and in Visual editor Run buttons appear only in the tutorial lines, not in the new lines I type. What am I missing?
